# Eslint errors on angular.js 1.x

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2017, eslint

on VS 2017 I am trying to build cordova app, I am getting Eslint (eqeqeq, etc) errors in angular.js file. can somebody tell me how to fix this errors?

Comment: eqeqeq means that you need to use '===' instead of '==' when doing comparisons

Comment: I know that but, it is error in angular.js why angular is giving this errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses javascript files, so ESLint is checking them based on rules in its configuration. If you don't want them, the solution is to turn off ESLint.

In VS2017:

"Tools" --> "Options", Drill into "Text Editor" --> "javascript/typescript" --> "ESLint"

Set it to false:

[image]